# Cannot connect to server after adding SignalR.Client nuget package

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, client

I'm trying to create a Blazor server app which sends a notification to other clients after one has submitted some input. I'm basically following the tutorial found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app

However, merely by adding the SignalR.Client nuget package, the client can no longer connect to the server ("Attempting to reconnect to the server: 1 of 8"), any idea what's wrong here?

I'm using .Net v7.0 here.

Comment: [Could you kindly check the repo first ?](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/BlazorChat)

Comment: Please show the references in the `.proj` file I'm suspecting an incompatible client was installed.

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" Version="2.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="8.0.0" />

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plotly.Blazor" Version="2.18.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Strangely, if I create a new Blazor WebAssembly app, I can add SignalR.Client and run without problem, how come?